# Accept multiple types using one stringstream function parameter

Tags: c++

I need to implement own stream class for error writing like `cout`. Here what im going to do is create a separate class and overload `<<` operator to accept any basic data types.
Simple idea is as fallow. but this program not compiled.

error
`error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const wchar_t [20]' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <sstream>

class ErrorWriter
{
public:
std::wstringstream& ErrorWriter::operator<<(std::wstringstream& ss){
        //write to file
      //write to console
        return ss;
    }
};

int main(){
  ErrorWriter eout;
  eout << L"this is first error";
  eout << L"\nThis second error" << 1 << 2.5 << true;
}
```

So My question

1. How to accept all the basic type argument using one function parameter (I do not need to write multiple operate overloader for each data type).
2. How other streams like `cout` ,`stringstream`  implement this
3. wstringstream can constructed by `wchar_t`

   `std::wstringstream ss(L"this is first error");`

So why it cannot convert to wstringstream on the fly (by works as conversion constructor)

Comment: Why do you want to convert `wchar_t` literals into wstringstreams in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't think there is any obvious way to do this.
2. The `basic_stringstream` constructor taking a string is declared [`explicit`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/explicit-ctors.html) - hence the conversion doesn't automatically happen.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is just to have a writer that can take arbitrary parameters (using std::ostream to do the conversion), then something like this will work.

```
class ErrorWriter
{
public:
  // Omit constructor and file_log initialization

  template<typename T>
  ErrorWriter& operator<<(const T& item) {
    file_log << item;
    std::cout << item;
    return *this;
  }

private:
  std::ofstream file_log;
};
```